# How to solve this equation in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematica

How do I solve this equation in Mathematica? Using the `NSolve` command doesn't work!

```
0.59*Sqrt[x]*Sin[0.2*Sqrt[x]] + 1.7*(Cos[0.3*Sqrt[x]] - 
    Coth[0.1*Sqrt[x]]*Sin[0.8*Sqrt[x]]) = 0
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

use ==, the test operator for equality, not =, the assignment operator

Comment: doesn't work, this is not the problem, please

Comment: You need to be more descriptive in your question. What error message does Mathematica give? Do you know there are actually solutions? From your use of = instead of ==, I'm guessing you aren't a Mathematica veteran. The problem is probably that you misused the function, and didn't provide the correct arguments, so Mathematica just spit out whatever you typed in unevaluated. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

May you could use few calls to FindRoot,like this one:

```
FindRoot[0.59 Sqrt[x] Sin[0.2 Sqrt[x]] + 1.7 (Cos[0.3 Sqrt[x]] - Coth[0.1 Sqrt[x]] Sin[0.8 Sqrt[x]]) ==  0, {x, 2}]
```

Does this suffices your purpose?

Comment: Of course, it is imperative that you come up with a good seed for `FindRoot[]`. :)